StoreKit 2 In-App Purchase - How to test with sandbox id using TestFlight?
I am currently trying to add auto-renewable In-App purchase subscription choices (one monthly and one yearly) to my app using SubscriptionStoreView and the modifiers .onInAppPurchaseCompletion, .subscriptionStatusTask, and .manageSubscriptionsSheet. I know that I can test this via Xcode with the .storeKit configuration file and that seems to be going pretty well. However, I would like to be able to test via TestFlight also. There are several Apple Developer Forum posts that seem to indicate that this is possible by setting up a sandbox user id in App Store Connect and then going to Settings -> App Store -> Sandbox Account (on my phone) and entering that sandbox user id that I just set up. Some posts suggest that this is presumably so that TestFlight will use that sandbox id when my app is running and not my personal user account when trying to buy subscriptions.
Unfortunately, underneath where it says Settings -> App Store -> "Sandbox Account", it also says "This account will only be used for testing your in-app purchases while developing locally. Your existing App Store account will be used for TestFlight apps."
So, it would seem that we cannot use a Sandbox Account for TestFlight if I'm understanding this correctly. I'm also assuming that "locally" from the above statement means that either my phone needs to be plugged into my Mac OR that I'm using Xcode and a .storekit file to test. That's fine for my initial testing but a big problem for some of my TestFlight testers because they do NOT have a Mac.
So now for the big questions... How are we supposed to have our testers be able to test via TestFlight then? Is it even possible? If so, what are the steps to set this up?
Sorry but this is so confusing and Apple's doc does not make this any clearer. Does anyone know how this is supposed to work with TestFlight? I'm not really comfortable just testing in Xcode and then hoping it works when it gets released in App Store. TIA.

Your conclusion is correct Sandbox is for local and TestFlight uses your Apple ID to use another Apple ID you need to change the id on the device settings > Apple ID > Media & Purchases

@lorem ipsum - So, are you saying that if they go to Settings > Apple ID > Media & Purchases, that they can log out of their personal account and login using the sandbox id? Will it let you use a sandbox id to log in? Does this completely log them out of their Apple ID or just for purchases? Sorry, I just want to make sure that I understand before having anyone try this.

This will log them out of all of their purchases and while I have not tried using a Sandbox ID I would expect that the Sandbox ID does not work because a Sandbox ID cannot be a an Apple ID. Sandbox is for local testing.

@lorem ipsum - Ok. That's kind of what I thought also. So, I guess the question remains for how can we effectively/properly test this with TestFlight? Seems like we can't reset transactions. So, I'm not sure how my testers can really test this part of my app. Now I know why people hate this :(

TestFlight users use their real Apple ID to test purchases.  They are not charged for in app purchases made in TestFlight builds.

TestFlight is meant for testing for a “real” scenario. To replicate what your users would experience. Without the cash transaction.

Thank you both for responding. I understand what you're saying and that my testers aren't getting charged. I just wish there was a way to "reset" purchases instead of waiting for it to basically reset itself in a given amount of time, which is what seems to be happening. For example, I can purchase either subscription, upgrade, etc. and in then several hours, it's apparently revoked or expired. So, I have no way to reset it on demand or set it like I've never purchased a subscription at all. I guess in a production environment that makes sense but it's frustrating from a testing standpoint.

TestFlight builds are App Store release builds. In app purchases are made using the user's real Apple ID but they are not charged.
The purchase dialog informs the user that they will not be charged.
